# Remove class if select value is "24" in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a little jQuery script, that adds a few form-groups when clicking an "add" button. The form contains `<select>`'s, and I want to unhide/show a div, when a certain value is selected in a `select`. This is the div I want to show:

```
    <div id="smash_select" class="nodisplay form-group col-md-2 col-lg-2">\
      <span class="form-bar"></span>\
      <label for="smash_type' + name + '">Win type</label>\
      <select id="smash_type' + name + '" name="smash_type' + name + '" class="form-control input-sm">\
        <optgroup label="Games">\
          <option value="solo">Solo wins</option>\
          <option value="team">Team wins</option>\
        </optgroup>\
      </select>\
    </div>\
```

I thought this would work:

```
if($("#smash_type' + name + '").val(24)) {
  $("#smash_select").removeClass("nodisplay");
}
```

But it doesn't, which I don't get. The whole script can be found [*here*](http://hastebin.com/poruwujoge.xml).

How would I show/remove a class when a `select` has a certain value, and add the class again, when the value changes?
I'm sort of stuck here :)

Comment: if ( $("#smash_type' + name + '").val() == 24)....

Answer (score 0):

Now you're setting the value to a number

```
$(element).val("value_to_set")
```

You'd want to get the value with just

```
$(element).val()
```

and as the value is always a string, either convert the value, check against a string, or do non-strict comparison

```
if( $("#smash_type" + name).val() == 24 ) {
    $("#smash_select").removeClass("nodisplay");
}
```

Note that your ID's seem to be quite invalid

Comment: I'm not exactly a "jQuery" person here, why the first two lines, and how is my ID invalid? :)

Comment: The first two lines only explain the issue, the code you need is in the third snippet. Your ID's *seem* at least somewhat strange, as they contain spaces, plus signs and quotes in the HTML, and seem to do the same in jQuery.

Comment: Well, it could also be that you have a `<select>` element, with two options, neither of which has the value "24", so matter what you select in that select, the value will *never* be "24" ?

Comment: Thank you, @adeneo, though I still need it to "change the color to red" again, when "24" is no longer selected.

Comment: Thank you @adeno, saved my day!